# Create custom class of unwrapped Parse objects (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I'm trying to create a class of date objects. The objects reflect values unwrapped from a Parse query result, which was passed from a segue. The result is a user-chosen retail location with dates of availability.

I've been able to extract each date from the result then display each in the desired format with NSDateFormatter, which results in two lines of let code per value. I'm stuck on grouping these values together in a class (or struct or enum?) for organization and reference purposes. Because each value is unwrapped with "object.objectForKey(name: String)" then turned into string, I haven't found specific documentation or SO threads that address grouping such values together.

Help please. Links to relevant docs/SO threads or suggestions would be appreciated for this Swift/iOS beginner.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use getDataInBackgroundWithBlock instead

Comment: This is very close to being just a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Or in this case, give some more details on how to use this rather than just name-dropping it.

Comment: Im working with parse and structs now, Im new to programming but I posted a question that is using parse. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392403/displaying-parse-images-in-uicollectionview-parse-com ), It takes arrays of texts and accesses them. Not sure if this is will help

Comment: @GreenReid I can call for the data from Parse without an issue. My question pertains to the organization of said data post-query.