# Displaying Parse Images in UICollectionView Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview, uicollectionview

Im new to ios programming so thank you for your patience. I am creating a collection view with images and labels downloaded from parse.com backend.  I am able to display the labels perfectly in the collection view now I am trying to get the corresponding images as well.

I am uncertain how to do so . PLEASE HELP SOS

here is my function

```
// Get Brands
func getBrand () {

    // Create PFQuery
    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "BrandInfo")

     // Call findobjects
     query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // refresh array
        self.brands = [String]()

        // loop through array
        for brandObject in objects! {

        // get PFObjects
        let brandName:String? = (brandObject as! PFObject)["Name"] as? String

            if brandName != nil {
                self.brands.append(brandName!)

             }


        let brandpic:PFFile? = (brandObject as! PFObject)["Image"] as? PFFile
```

Comment: Straight from the Parse guides, https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files-images
You'll need to stream the data then set the image when you've received it all

Comment: Ive used the guide and came up with this ...

Comment: let brandPicture = brandObject["Image"] as! PFFile
                    brandPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        
                        if(error == nil){
                            
                            let image:UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                            self.pics.append(image)
                            
                        }
                    })
                    
                    println(self.pics.count)

Comment: Note that your print statement isn't in the block, so it will most likely show 0. Put it in the block to see when you get the image. Also, make sure to set your imageview with the image you got in the block as well.

Comment: Thank you for all your help . I was able to get it to work once now but it crashed . Made a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494669/uicollectionview-and-parse-images-swift-no-error-but-crash